# Unable to retrieve the values in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pymongo

I have used pymongo and retrieved all the values in collection which is stored in mongo atlas and I wanted only lat so I have stored all the lat like this.

```
a_float = [a['Lat'] for a in results1]
```

where  results1=collection1.find({}) and collection1 = db["Latitude"]

Now in flask I'm trying to compare the input lat with mongo lat. Every time  else condition is being executed. My flask code is as follows

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route("/echo", methods=['POST'])
def echo():
    a=request.form['lat']
    b=request.form['long']

    if a in a_float:
        msg = "present"
        return render_template('root.html', msg=msg, a=a, b=b)
    else:
        msg = "absent"

    return render_template('root.html', msg=msg, a=a, b=b)
```

My HTML code home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST" action="/echo">

        Enter the lat<input type="text" name = 'lat' >
        Enter the long<input type="text" name = 'long' >

        <input type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

root.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<form>        
    </form>
    <body>


{{ msg }}
    Lat : {{a}}
    Long : {{b}}

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the future please post your trace back or error that you are getting that will help people answer your question more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your comparison is the same type?

Try converting before comparison if the list element has float values:

```
a = float(request.form['long'])
```

Or

```
a = request.form.get('long', type=float)
```

[See more about this way here](http://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get)